# Update query hangs in node-oracledb module

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I am working with node-oracledb (**3.1.2**) module. Everything is working fine except update query. I am able to fire select, insert queries but when I try to fire upate query, then it seems query is getting hanged (no error, no result). I am writing the below code:

**For creating connection:**

```
module.exports.createErpConnection = async () => {
   try {
       connection = await oracleDB.getConnection({
           user: constants.databaseCredentials.user,
           password: constants.databaseCredentials.password,
           connectString: `${constants.databaseCredentials.connectString}/${constants.databaseCredentials.databaseName}`
       });

       if (connection) {
           response.status = 1;
           response.connection = connection
       } else {
           response.status = 0;
           response.message = constants.databaseStatus.ERP_DATABASE_CONNECTION_NOT_ESTABLISHED
       }
   } catch (exception) {
       response.status = 0;
       response.message = exception;
   } finally {
       return response;
   }
};
```

**Firing update query:**

```
async function updateProductStatInErp(connection) {
  let sql = `UPDATE product_master SET UPDATED_STAT='N'`;
  let options = {outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT, autoCommit: true};
  const res = await connection.connection.execute(sql, {}, options)
  // I am not getting either response nor error
}
```

**Do I need to do anything addition for firing update query??**

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue just by writing **execute** statement in try and catch block. Here is the code:

```
 try {
      const res = await connection.connection.execute(sql, {}, options)
      console.log('======= 185 =======', res)
  } catch (exception) {
      console.log('====== 186 =====', exception)
    }
Result =>> ====== 185 ======= { rowsAffected: 490 }
```